# $Y =\min\{X, 10\}$ and $X$~geometric with parameter $p$. Find Probability mass function of $Y$, and $E(Y)$

Tags: probability-theory

I looked at this as saying that $P(Y=k) = P(X < 10) + P(X=10) + 1 - P(X \le 10)$.

Then for each pmf of X I just put in the summation of each of those according to the geometric distribution. Is that the correct path?

Or Should it be that $P(\min(X, 10) = k) = P(10 \ge X)$?
The ten is throwing me off, instead of having a second random variable there.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ has a $p$-parameter geometric distribution, so for all $k\in \{1, 2, ...\}$ then $\mathsf P(X=k) = p(1-p)^{k-1}$

$Y$ is the minimum of $10$ or $X$, so if $X<10$ then $Y=X$, else if $X\geq 10$ then $Y=10$.

$Y$ must lie within $\{1, 2, ... 10\}$.

So, what is $\mathsf P(Y=10)$, and $\mathsf P(Y=k)$ for all $k\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ ?

Then find: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y) & = 10\; \mathsf P(Y=10) + \sum_{k=1}^9 k\; \mathsf P(Y=k)
\\ & = ?\end{align}$$

Comment: So, I found P(y = 10) = 1 - summation from y =0 to 9 of p(1-p)^y.  Then P(y = k) = Summation from y = 0 to 9 of p(a-p)^y.  Then when I went to find the expectation I plugged everything into the sums and expanded it and got 10 - 10p - 9p(1-p) - 8p(1-p)^2 - ... - p(1-p)^9. Then from there I am not sure how to write the finished product, is that the final answer, or since this is looking like a geometric pattern do we then say that the mean of geometric is 1/p, and relate that to my new geometric pattern? Does that make sense?

Comment: Mostly, yes.  This is *not* a geometric distribution, so you need to use the definition of expectation $\mathsf E(Y)=\sum_y y P(Y=y)$.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to deal with minima is
$$
P(Y \geq y) = P(X \geq y, 10 \geq y) = \begin{cases}
P(X\geq y) &: y \leq 10 \\
0 & : y>10
\end{cases}
$$
Now write $P(Y=y) = P(Y\geq y) - P(Y\geq y+1)$, so
$$
P(Y=y) = \begin{cases}
P(X=y) &: y \leq 9 \\
P(X\geq 10) &: y=10 \\
0 &: y > 10
\end{cases}
$$
Does this help?